# Cannot find matha12.mf error although the file exists

Tags: errors

I recently started to use Windows and now setting up Latex. (I was a long-time Mac user, so am almost beginner for Windows.)

I think the installation has been completed, but the following error message is shown during the typeset.

I have confirmed that the file called "metha12.mf" exists in C:\w32tex\share\texmf-dist\tex\latex\mathabx\source.

How can I resolve this issue?

(c:/w32tex/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)name = matha12, rootname = matha, pointsize = 12
mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

kpathsea: Running mktexmf matha12.mf

The command name is C:\w32tex\bin\mktexmf
Cannot find matha12.mf.

! Font U/matha/m/n/12=matha12 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fou
nd.
 
                   relax 
l.123 \maketitle